# Globally installation of packages with npm

Tags: npm, package.json

I have a question regarding the package manager npm and the meaning of installing the package globally.

For example I work often with react, should I install react globally?

```
npm install -g react react-dom
```

Does this mean that next time when I do

```
npx creat-react-app my-app
```

It will get the package from the global or it does not matter and it will still download it locally inside my-app?

Because I really do not understand the idea behind installing globally.

Because if I want to use a package it should be mentioned in package.json, if it is in package.json it is then located in node_module ... so yeah ...

Could anyone give me better insight?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

React library can be installed globally on your local machine. In development there is no real reason to do that since you might not have the latest version and this might cause issues.
Better practise is to use react on project level by using the command you stated above `npx create-react-app my-app`

If you push code to a server the `package.json` file will install the dependencies (React, React DOM,..) to build your project.

Read more here : https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

> If you've previously installed create-react-app globally via npm
> install -g create-react-app, we recommend you uninstall the package
> using npm uninstall -g create-react-app or yarn global remove
> create-react-app to ensure that npx always uses the latest version.

You can check what packages are installed globally using:

```
npm list -g --depth 0
```